# How to keep a spotify refresh token remotely in node.js on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, cloud, spotify

Every 24 hours, the dynos on heroku cycle, meaning that my login token for spotify is lost until I log in again, making the app not work until I log in to get another refresh token. I was wondering if anyone knows of a free service out there where I can literally just read and write the token string with node.js so it will persist when the dynos cycle. I was looking into firebase's realtime database and cloud firestore, and mongoose for mongo db but it seems like a lot of extra work to set up for one string. Does anyone have a recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people will pair a Heroku app with the free tier of Heroku Postgres. When you set it up, you get the PostgreSQL connection credentials provided to your app in an environment variable. You get 10,000 rows for free, so plenty to just store a few pieces of data like the token values.

https://www.heroku.com/postgres

The other services you mention will let you store NoSQL data, so you won't even have to make a table. Firestore for example would be a good choice for this, if you're willing to set up a Google Cloud account. Their free tier would cover what you want to do. You'd set it up a similar way, providing Google Cloud connection credentials to your Heroku app in the form of a custom set environment variable.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/